# How can I force sublclipse to commit?

Tags: eclipse, svn, commit, subclipse

how can I force sublclipse to commit code to repository even though it thinks some files are "outdated"?

Comment: Is your branch up to date?  When you do an 'svn up' does that update the files?  From the cmd line when you run 'svn stat' what do you see?  Usually subclipse works great but sometimes I have to use the cmd line to see what is really going on when it breaks.

Answer (score 2):

The server rejects commits if the working copy is outdated.  The client cannot override this.  Just run the update option so that your working copy is up to date for the changed items.

Comment: Well it wasn't really outdated, because it wasn't possible. But if I run update, it will modify the files I don't want too and revert my changes back, right?

Comment: If the server says it is outdated, then it is.  You should read the section of the book on Mixed Revision working copies.  Even a single user can have their working copy out of date.  Update will not revert your changes.  It might create conflicts.  You can use the Synchronize option to preview what is going to happen.